# video upload timed out before it could be completed - facebook graph api - angular

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to upload a video file from my computure using facebook graph api Angular and facebook-js-sdk

here is the following method that I am using to upload a video

```
  initFacebook() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'appId',
      xfbml: true,
      cookie: true,
      version: 'v16.0'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        this.storeLoggedUser();
      } else {
        console.error('Couldn\'t authenticate to Facebook');
      }
    });
  }

  

  createVideo(videoFile: File): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      const videoData = new FormData();
      videoData.append("source", videoFile);
      videoData.append("title", "test title");


      FB.api(`/act_${this.accountId}/advideos?fields=id,name`, "post", videoData, (response: any) => {
        observer.next(response);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
```

I am getting the following error

```
{
    "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 390,
    "error_subcode": 1363030,
    "is_transient": true,
    "error_user_title": "Video Upload Time Out",
    "error_user_msg": "Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AI6AbowqTGtMs6ZxlwWUyfE"
}
```

I was expecting the video to be uploaded to the adAcount library so I can use it's id later on

Comment: You don't need to tell us which permissions you granted, if those were the issue, you would get a completely different error message. _"This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large."_ - what else is there to say, it is likely either one of those two reasons. Resp. the combination of both, if your video is large and your connection speed low ...

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your time, but I have checked my speed connection, and the video file size is only 5,63 Mo

Comment: Okay, then the error message is probably misleading, and caused by the fact that you are not uploading the data in a correct format to begin with. You can not send a `FormData` instance as the content of one single parameter, that makes no sense - you need to send _just_ the `FormData`, and nothing else. So append the `title` value to your FormData instance, same as you did with `source` - and then pass `videoData` as the third parameter in your `FB.api` call _directly_.

Comment: @CBroe I really appreciate your time, but I have already tried that and it didn't work, and the error  message is  misleading as you mentioned, I have tried to read the documentation and see if there is any example available online, but I have found none

Comment: Show what _exactly_ you tried, please, otherwise we can't know if you did it correctly or not.

Comment: this is what I tried first, but it shows the same error  
` 
 createVideo(videoFile: File): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      const videoData = new FormData();
      videoData.append("source", videoFile);
      videoData.append("title", "test title");


      FB.api(`/act_${this.accountId}/advideos?fields=id,name`, "post", videoData, (response: any) => {
        observer.next(response);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
`

Comment: Where's the documentation for that endpoint?

Comment: here is the documentation I followed [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/advideos/#Creating) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: Ah, Facebook as bad as it gets once again. No mention which parameters are actually required, anchor links that lead to nowhere ... Sorry, can't help much with that. Not even sure if `FB.api` even supports using FormData, the documentation for that only says it is an "object" containing the parameters. But considering that the SDK needs to at least add the access token to the parameters, I would not be too sure if it actually handles FormData correctly. I'd perhaps try to make the request using AJAX/fetch, and see if that gives a different result.

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much for your effort and time, but I have already tried to use  AJAX but the result is the same, and the problem is there is no example in the documentation itself nor on the Internet, anyway thank you again I really appreciate that I will keep digging until I find it then I will update this question so someone else can benefit from it in the future